# Removing Blank Cell

Tags: excel, vba

In column A, we have numbers of 1 to 10 respectively
And in column B we hold letters a to j which do not have order
We removed  4 letters
I do not want to change column A but column B removes her empty cells and  letters writing following 
The following code removes rows with empty cells:

[image]

```
Sub DeleteEmptyRows()

'   Deletes the entire row within the selection if the ENTIRE row contains no data.

Dim i As Long
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select

With Application
    ' Turn off calculation and screenupdating to speed up the macro.
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection.Rows(i)) = 0 Then Selection.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i

    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you not replying to the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will loop through the rangeAreas, copy the contents in Column B of that area, remove the blanks, and but the results back in column b, I requires column Z as a helper column

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim RangeArea As Range, x

    For Each RangeArea In Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1).Areas
        x = RangeArea.Rows.Count
        RangeArea.Offset(, 1).Copy [z1]
        Columns("Z:Z").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        RangeArea.Offset(, 1).Value = Range("Z1:Z" & x).Value
        Range("Z:Z").Delete

    Next RangeArea

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand how you get from your first picture to the second, but if you start from the second, this will get you to the third.

```
Sub x()

On Error Resume Next 'avoid error if no blank cells
Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete shift:=xlUp
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Now, if I want to run this item in a selected range, how I do ?
For example, in range from B1 to B10 and B13 to B22 and B25 to B34 and ....

Comment: @alirezataghizadeh you can use: `Union(Range("B1:B10"), Range("B13:B22"), Range("B25:B34")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete`

Comment: @GMalc I believe the issue is that all the cells shift up,

Comment: @Davesexcel the OPs example shows only the cells being deleted, And since `shift:=xlUp` is the default when you delete a cell, i don't add it.  In the OPs comment he ask for specific ranges, so i figured he did not want the cells between the ranges to be affected.

Comment: The point is, just the cells in that range need to shift up, run your line of code and see what happens.

Comment: @Davesexcel - fair point, though the OP has not clarified. Between us we seem to have covered both angles.